# How to compute approximate probability with z value?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

This is the question:

An airplane with room for 100 passengers has a total baggage limit of 6000 lb. Suppose that the total weight of the baggage checked by an individual passenger is a random variable x with a mean value of 48 lb and a standard deviation of 18 lb. If 100 passengers will board a flight, what is the approximate probability that the total weight of their baggage will exceed the limit? (Hint: With n = 100, the total weight exceeds the limit when the average weight x exceeds 6000/100.) (Round your answer to four decimal places.)

From my calculation I get a z value of 6.66 which would be 100%.  Its being marked wrong by my teacher and I cannot figure out why.  Every similar example I get a realistic z score and can find the value.  But 48-60 is -12 18/(sqrt(100)= 1.8 -12/1.8 is -6.66.

Comment: So did you get 6.66 or -6.66? These would correspond to different values of the normal distribution function (I am assuming you are using the normal approximation).

Comment: You think it's certain that the limit will be exceeded?  But the mean weight is just $4800$...

Comment: @lulu I don't think it is certain.  Not to be snarky, but that's why I asked the question.  I would appreciate any insight you might have here.

Comment: My point was just that $100\%$ was intuitively wrong.  After all, the mean weight is $4800$ so there is a $50\%$ probability that the luggage will weigh less than $4800$.  Indeed the standard deviation of the total weight is $18\times \sqrt {100}=180$ so the limit is, as you remark, a $6.\overline {66} \sigma$ event, making it effectively impossible.

Comment: @lulu thank you, I realize how i worded it and it was wrong.  The problem is I answered that it has 0 chance of happening.  I do not know what else that would be an acceptable answer.

Comment: I would have put $0$ as well.  Perhaps the numbers were in error?  The answer is so close to $0$ that whatever difference there is entirely insignificant compared to modeling noise (the process is not truly normal, the weight is not truly independent between two passengers, and so on).  do you know what the "official answer" was?

Comment: @lulu I'll have to ask my professor.  It might be that i didn't do decimal places.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We want to calculate the probability that the population mean exceeds $\frac{6000}{100}=60$

$P(x>60)=P(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}>\frac{60-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}})=P(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}>\frac{60-48}{18/\sqrt{100}})=P(z>\frac{60-48}{18/\sqrt{100}})=P(z>6.667)=1-\Phi (6.667)=\Phi (-6.667)$,

Note: z ~ N(0,1).

So, by using the R command $1-pnorm(\frac{60-48}{18/\sqrt{100}})$, we get 0.

So it is very unlikely that the weight of a single baggage will exceed 60, which means that the total weight is unlikely to exceed 6000.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_{100}$ represent the random baggage weights of each of the $n = 100$ passengers.  Then for each $i = 1, \ldots, 100$, each $X_i$ might be assumed to follow a normal distribution with mean $\mu = 48$ and standard deviation $\sigma = 18$.  If these weights are all independent, then their sum $$S = X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_{100} \sim \operatorname{Normal}\left(\mu_S = 100\mu = 4800, \sigma_S = \sigma\sqrt{100} = 180\right).$$  That is to say, the the mean of the total weight is $4800$ with a standard deviation of $180$.  Note here that I'm working with the total weight, not the average weight.  So the probability that the total weight exceeds the limit of $6000$ is $$\Pr[S > 6000] = \Pr\left[\frac{S - \mu_S}{\sigma_S} > \frac{6000 - 4800}{180}\right] = \Pr[Z > 6.667].$$  Note the direction of the inequality:  This probability corresponds to finding the probability that a standard normal random variable $Z$ is **more than 6.667 standard deviations greater than zero**.  Thus, the probability will be very, very tiny--close to zero, rather than close to $1$.  We would write $$\Pr[Z > 6.667] = 1 - \Phi(6.667) \approx 1.3083924686 \times 10^{-11},$$ in effect, it is less than a $1$ in $76$ billion chance.